# Can't get displacement to work Properly in 2.91

Tags: displacement

I want the displacement to displace outwards using the normals.

That is not what is happening, see picture:

[image: Displacement working wierdly]

You can see the bounding box, and you can see that the displacement is happening along one axis, pushing the whole thing up and to the side. It's like what used to happen when they first moved over to using the vector displacement node and people still tried to use just the multiply node.

I can achieve the result I want if I use the displacement modifier, but then I can't use adaptive subdivision (or can't figure out how to), so I have to subdivide the shit out of my object to get anything like the detail I want.

this is the setting I have in the subdivision modifier

[image: Subdivision Modifier settings]

Comment: Hello :). You're using a *Vector Displacement* node. Use a simple *Displacement* node instead and it should work :).

Comment: This was the perfect solution - in case anyone else needs a more specific answer I plugged my *Image Texture* color output into the Height input of the *DIsplacement* node, then Displacement out to Displacement in on the *Material Output* node